# How to fix "Unexpected end of JSON input" thrown on sending a POST request to the server using fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

I have a simple chatbox UI that is integrated into a chatbot developed using .netcore.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>   (anonymous) @ im.html:201

I'm thrown with this error after having a couple of conversations with the bot. Below is the input box I'm using to capture the text message.

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" class="bg-light" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" aria-describedby="button-addon2" class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 py-4" id="message">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button id="button-addon2" type="submit" class="btn btn-link" onclick="userMessage()"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When the user hits enter, I'm displaying the typed message in the UI and sending a POST request to the server to get a response.

```
 // User message layout
function userMessage() {
    var spinner = document.getElementById('textSpinner');
    var h5 = document.getElementById("h5");
    var inputBox = document.getElementById("message");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var inputValue = inputBox.value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    p.appendChild(text);

    if (inputValue === '' || !h5.innerText) {
        alert("Please sart the session first!");
    } else {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "media";

          /.../

        var chatArea = document.getElementById('chat-area')
        chatArea.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' })
        spinner.style.display = "none";
        interact(h5.innerText, inputValue);
    }
    inputBox.value = "";
}
```

Below is the POST request

```
   // POST user message
   function interact(userId, message) {
    var spinner = document.getElementById('textSpinner');
    spinner.style.display = "block";
    const payload = {
        userId: userId,
        utterance: message
    };

    fetch('Sessions/Interact', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => botMessage(data.Message))
        .then(() => spinner.style.display = "none")
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }
```

When I get the response from the server, I'm calling another function called `botMessage()` which is similar to the `userMessage()` that will display the bot message.
Can someone guide me as to why this error is thrown and is there any solution to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the response body from the server.

```
{
  "Message": "Hello, It's me. Let's start chatting shall we?",
  "Data": null
}
```

Comment: Is the entire response received and parsed as one? that often causes these kind of issues

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console to get the exact text content of the response. What does it look like?

Comment: It seems that when there's no more responses to give from the server, it is sending a 204, I think that's what causing the issue.

Comment: Does anyone know how to handle it such that on response 200 it'll go to `userMessage()` function with the `Message` parameter and on response 204 it'll do nothing.

Comment: I think that's the wrong approach. It seems to me like the response is malformed, try addressing this first.

Comment: Check `response.status` before returning `response.json()`

Comment: @JacobSchneider a 204 is _"No content"_, hence the _"Unexpected end of JSON input"_. OP just needs to deal with the various responses from their server

Comment: @Phil What causes the "*no content*"? If the request is designed to return information from the server, having an empty response seems incorrect, does it not?

Comment: @JacobSchneider I checked the server, and there are occurrences where it does return 204 responces.

Comment: That will be the source of your issues. As @Phil mentioned, you have the option of catching this behaviour, or you can address it server side. I would do the latter, but Phil seems to know what he's doing too. Check your requirements and use the most fitting approach.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the response handling as below. Is this approach I'm doing is correct? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

```
.then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
         return response.json()
         .then(data => botMessage(data.Message))
      } else if (response.status === 204) {
         return;
      }
    })           
    .then(() => spinner.style.display = "none")
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Looks good. Ideally you should check `response.ok` (for non-successful status codes) and throw an error or `return Promise.reject(response)` in those cases